# Which Square Enix triangle codes contain spoilers and which do not?

Tags: deus-ex-mankind-divided

In Deus Ex: Mankind Divided the player can find 35 triangle pieces as loot scattered throughout the world.  By viewing them in my inventory and scanning them (like a QR code) into the Deus Ex Universe mobile app, I can view/listen to behind-the-scenes interviews and artwork, similar to what was available in the Director's Cut of Deus Ex: Human Revolution.

The Eidos developers often tout their intention and ability to make Deus Ex games flow properly even for players who do things out of order (whether accidentally or on purpose).  Has Square Enix done the same with these triangles, or will any of them spoil the plot if I pick them up and view them before I'm "supposed" to?

Answer (score 12):

Numbering from left-to-right then top-to-bottom in the "Square Enix Members" section of the "Database", here is a breakdown of which triangles are safe to view at any time and which contain spoilers.  (There are no actual spoilers in this answer.)

1. safe - video Q&A about the franchise's mythology
2. safe - audio Q&A about environment design at location
3. safe - audio Q&A about environment design at location
4. safe - concept art
5. safe - video Q&A about loading screens in the metros
6. **MASSIVE SPOILER** - video Q&A; do NOT view or even look at the *name* of the triangle code in the app (i.e. don't even scan it) until you learn the identity of the individual you're supposed to meet during the mission that takes you to this area
7. **SPOILER** - audio Q&A about side quests; not too much is spoiled in the interview, but still best to wait until after the mission involving the character in the room where you find it
8. safe - audio Q&A about environment design, especially the location where you find it
9. safe - audio Q&A about design decisions for the location where you find it.  Actually worth listening to right away, as it points you toward a cool interactive feature you might otherwise miss.
10. safe - audio Q&A about environment design decisions at the location where you find it
11. safe - audio Q&A about level design, particularly the location where you find it
12. safe - video Q&A about the location where you find it
13. safe - video Q&A with actor
14. safe - video Q&A about design of the character in the location where you find it
15. mostly safe - video Q&A about the design history of the location where you find it; in the last 30 seconds the interviewees get into spoiler territory but don't actually reveal anything
16. safe - video Q&A with actor
17. **MASSIVE SPOILER** - audio Q&A about location and mission; the triangle is not available until the mission begins, but do NOT listen to it until after the mission is over
18. safe - video Q&A with actor
19. safe - video Q&A about the corporation that owns the location where you find it
20. mostly safe - audio Q&A about location and about Breach Mode. If you've completed even the intro of Breach Mode (or if you don't care about Breach Mode), then this won't spoil anything.
21. safe - audio Q&A about environment design
22. safe - video Q&A with actor
23. safe - video Q&A about the location where you find it
24. safe - extended video behind the scenes of the first "press hands-on" release of the game
25. safe - short audio Q&A about the organization using the location where you find it
26. safe - video Q&A with backstory about two cities in the world
27. safe - video Q&A with actor
28. broken - audio Q&A about location; SoundCloud can't find the file
29. mostly safe, but broken - audio Q&A about design of character and character model; it's possible that if you aren't paying close attention to the discoverables in the game, then this could spoil some information about the character.  On the other hand, the SoundCloud file for this Q&A is broken -- the second half of the interview is simply missing -- so there's not much reason to listen to it in the first place.
30. broken - audio Q&A about homage to Human Revolution; SoundCloud can't find the file
31. **SPOILER** - audio Q&A about level design of location; the content is safe, but the *name* of the entry contains a spoiler, so don't scan it until you're done with the location
32. **SPOILER** - video Q&A about narrative design at location; same issue as in 31
33. safe - extended audio Q&A about design of the encounter in this area
34. safe - concept art
35. safe - audio Q&A about visual FX at location

Please edit this post if you encounter any of the unknown pieces above.